# How to remove edges in OSMnx

Tags: python, osmnx

Questions about deleting edges from the osmnx network.

I wrote the code below to analyze using the following example.
example: https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/master/notebooks/13-isolines-isochrones.ipynb

My Code

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
from descartes import PolygonPatch
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon
%matplotlib inline
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)

point = 35.334023, 129.314150
network_type = 'drive'
trip_times = [10, 20, 30, 40] #in minutes
travel_speed = 20 #walking speed in km/hour

# download the street network
G = ox.graph_from_point(point, network_type='drive', dist=8000)
ox.plot_graph(G, node_size=1, edge_color='#999999', node_color='#dc4343', edge_linewidth=0.5, figsize=(15, 20))
```

**In here, I want to delete a specific edge from the configured network.
For example**

```
edges = edges.loc[edges['name'].str.contains("천산로")==False]
```

**It has yet to solve these problems. I would appreciate it if you give me a good answer.**

Comment: I would encourage you to read the OSMnx documentation and then, in particular, the NetworkX documentation as removing an edge from a graph is basic functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all graph edges, check for the edge name and then remove the edge if applicable:

```
for u, v, name in nxG.edges(name='name'):
    if name == 'some_name': nxG.remove_edge(u, v)
```